# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near '-' , Grant View SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just trying to run the code I got from one of the sites on the internet (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/cursor-in-sql-server/) which aims to give 'VIEW' access to every object in the database

This is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dba_ExecGrantViewDefinition]  
(@login VARCHAR(30))  
AS  
  
SET NOCOUNT ON  

CREATE TABLE #runSQL 
(runSQL VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL)  

--Declare @execSQL varchar(2000), @login varchar(30), @space char (1), @TO char (2)  
DECLARE @execSQL VARCHAR(2000), @space CHAR (1), @TO CHAR (2)  

SET @to = 'TO' 
SET @execSQL = 'Grant View Definition ON '  
SET @login = REPLACE(REPLACE (@login, '[', ''), ']', '') 
SET @login = '[' + @login + ']' 
SET @space = ' ' 

INSERT INTO #runSQL  
SELECT @execSQL + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + [name] + @space + @TO + @space + @login  
FROM sys.all_objects s  
WHERE type IN ('P','V','FN','IF','TF')  
AND is_ms_shipped = 0  
ORDER BY s.type, s.name  

SET @execSQL = ''  

Execute_SQL:  

SET ROWCOUNT 1  

SELECT @execSQL = runSQL FROM #runSQL 

PRINT @execSQL --Comment out if you don't want to see the output 

EXEC (@execSQL) 

DELETE FROM #runSQL WHERE runSQL = @execSQL
```

When i executed this code to one of my object with name `'dbo.testing_2022-03-17'`
I get the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near '-'.

can someone suggest what is not in accordance with the code in my object name

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to spot in the literal strings; for example a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Comment: try `dbo.[testing_2022-03-17]`

Comment: If you don't understand the SQL in the dynamic statement, [edit] an example of the (failing) dynamic SQL into your question. Also it's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: Also note that syntax like `'[' + @login + ']'` is **not** injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME` to both properly quote and escape the value. If the value is also an object that should already exist in the database, then you should also be making attempts to validate that that the object does exist in the database.

Comment: WTF. Why on earth would you want to do `@space + @TO + @space` as opposed to just having the string `' TO '`?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some of the issues mentioned in the comments, the reason behind the error seems to be the original author used `[name]` to add the table name, rather than actually adding the square brackets around the `name` column.

Change this line:

```
SELECT @execSQL + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + [name] + @space + @TO + @space + @login
```

To:

```
SELECT @execSQL + QUOTENAME(schema_name(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + @space + @TO + @space + @login
```